# Count multiple fields in MongoDB using python

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this simple mongodb query:

```
db.checks_reports_data_df8.find({"report_id": str(report["_id"])})
```

The collection `checks_reports_data_df8` is having some fields like "`success`" (can be 0 or 1) and `is_listed` (can be 0 or 1).

What I need is to be able to get the counts of all fields where `success = 1` as `count_success` and all fields where `is_listed = 1` as `count_listed`. 
The final result will be something like all the results from the query above + count_success and count_listed

I suppose that this can be done using the aggregation framework.

**EDIT:**
To clarify, here is the return from the query above:

```
{'is_listed': 0, 'success': 1, '_id': ObjectId('54dca9920e13a771a44433d4'), 'report_id': u'54dca97758a5d3a37c8b4567'}
{'is_listed': 0, 'success': 1, '_id': ObjectId('54dca9920e13a771a44433a3'), 'report_id': u'54dca97758a5d3a37c8b4567'}
{'is_listed': 1, 'success': 1, '_id': ObjectId('54dca9920e13a771a44433c2'), 'report_id': u'54dca97758a5d3a37c8b4567'}
```

What I need, is to have `count_success = 3` (the sum of the success=1 fields) and `count_listed = 1` (the sum of the is_listed=1 fields)

Comment: For clarity, could you post a sample document and your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
db.checks_reports_data_df8.aggregate([
        {
                '$match' : 
                    {
                        "report_id": str(report["_id"])
                    }
        },
        {
            '$group' : 
                {
                    '_id': '$report_id',
                    count_success :{'$sum': '$success'},
                    count_is_listed:{'$sum':'$is_listed'}
                }
        }
])
```